# Checking if array key is empty or not

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through a `foreach`, and I only want to execute some code if the value is **not an empty string**. There are multiple keys with just an empty string as a property.

I have the following:

```
<?php foreach ( $images as $x ):
        if ( $x['description'] != '' ):  
?>
        <p class="description"><?php echo $x['description'] ?></p>
<?php else:
          echo 'else!';
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

However, it is doing both: executing both the `if` and the `else`.

Here is the array I'm looping through:

```
ARRAY (SIZE=7)
  0 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 111
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'THIS IS THE TITLE' (LENGTH=17)
      'CAPTION' => STRING 'HTTPS://SOUNDCLOUD.COM/LATENIGHTTALES/LNT-BNB-ALBUM-MINI-MIX' (LENGTH=60)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING 'THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION FOR THIS IMAGE. ' (LENGTH=40)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/BEAUTY.PNG' (LENGTH=63)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/BEAUTY.PNG' (LENGTH=63)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/BEAUTY.PNG' (LENGTH=63)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/BEAUTY.PNG' (LENGTH=63)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
  1 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 154
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'PLACEHOLDER' (LENGTH=11)
      'CAPTION' => STRING 'CAPTION2' (LENGTH=8)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING 'DESCRIPTION2' (LENGTH=12)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER.PNG' (LENGTH=68)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER.PNG' (LENGTH=68)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER.PNG' (LENGTH=68)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER.PNG' (LENGTH=68)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
  2 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 155
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'TITLE3' (LENGTH=6)
      'CAPTION' => STRING 'CAPTION3' (LENGTH=8)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING 'DESCRIPTION 3' (LENGTH=13)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER1.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER1.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER1.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER1.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
  3 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 156
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'PLACEHOLDER' (LENGTH=11)
      'CAPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER2.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER2.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER2.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER2.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
  4 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 157
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'PLACEHOLDER' (LENGTH=11)
      'CAPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER3.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER3.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER3.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER3.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
  5 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 158
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'PLACEHOLDER' (LENGTH=11)
      'CAPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER4.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER4.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER4.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER4.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
  6 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 159
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'PLACEHOLDER' (LENGTH=11)
      'CAPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/PNG' (LENGTH=9)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER5.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
      'WIDTH' => INT 300
      'HEIGHT' => INT 400
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER5.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 72
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER5.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 400
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/03/PLACEHOLDER5.PNG' (LENGTH=69)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 300
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 400
```

Comment: You mean empty value? There is not seem to be any empty `key` string.

Comment: Try changing if ( $x['description'] != '' ): to if(isset($x['description']) and strlen($x['description']) > 0):

Comment: @tmyie I don't see why you need an `else` there. Your code should work fine without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do You mean by:

> executing both the if and the else.

Do You see both the `description` AND 'else!' for the same array row ? (cant see how that could be possible)

Or do You mean the parent array element should not be parsed when empty value detected ? And now You are seeing both `if else` statement results for diffrent array rows (but one parent array row)

Can You please modify the code in such way (and show part of results with both of them):

```
<?php
   foreach ( $images as $index => $x ):
        if ( $x['description'] != '' ):  
?>
            <p class="description">
                <?php echo $index . ':' . $x['description'] ?>
            </p>
<?php   else: echo $index . 'else!';
    endif;
endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Yes, I see both `description` and `else!`.

Comment: Can You please check code from the answer above @tmyie and share results.

Comment: Okay, I seem to get both the description and the else: `ARRAY:THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION FOR THIS IMAGE.

ARRAY:DESCRIPTION2

ARRAY:DESCRIPTION 3

ARRAYELSE!ARRAYELSE!ARRAYELSE!ARRAYELSE!`

Comment: And ? It worked correctly from my point of view.

What result would You except ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php foreach ( $images as $x ) {
    if ( !empty($x['description'])) {
       ?><p class="description"><?php echo $x['description'] ?></p><?php
    }else{
       echo 'else!';
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you  could use trim for string cases to remove  breaklines and empty espaces before compare